# SSRS reporting Service authentication

Tags: php, sql-server, reporting-services, yii, ssrs-2012

1. I have a couple of reports on my SSRS reporting service that gather data from a SQL server database.
2. I have a web app on PHP using Yii framework in another server.
3. I need to link the reports of my SSRS in order to show them on my web app.

Everything works great, I just create a html link to the report and can be displayed, however, everytime I'm going to open a report, microsoft promps a window asking for credentials (domain/user - password).

Problem is, not every user to connect into my web page knows the domain/user and password of my SQL server and actually I dont want to. So the real question is:

From the reporting service, there is a way to set a default "Domain/user - password" data for my reports in my SSRS reporting service in order to avoid the authentication popup? or directly disable this feature? Those reports doesnt show critical information so there is no problem if they can be accessed directly.

Comment: You basically have two options. Either you will need to give every user access rights to your database, or then you need a technical service account that is used to access the database every time the report is used. The latter should be the better option, when we're talking about merely accessing a report. I don't know anything about PHP, so someone else can fill you in about the actual details.

Comment: @JuhaK thanks for your answer, Can you explain me how can I set this technical account? I have plenty access to both SSRS reporting and database conf.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with PHP stuff; basically you need a technical service account on the SQL Server that has necessary read-access on the database. Then you use the credentials of this service account when your application requests data from the database instead of the user's credentials. Your DB does not "know" who is accessing the report, only that someone has requested data.